# Lua key event with variables (unified remote)

Tags: lua

i need some help with unified remote (lua) scriptfile for a keyboard / mouse action.
need this events:
"F5" toggles (enable / disable) an elevator
down right mouse button while key.down "e" start the elevator.

action on a button:

1. press: lift goes up >>OK!works!
2. press: lift stops >>OK!Works!
3. press: lift jumps back too ground. >>OK!Works!

but:
it seems, there is an open Mouse.up event, so i had to do a 4. press only for final mouse.up...

my code:

```
--@help Command 7
actions.command7 = function ()
    
    use = not use;
if (use) then
    kb.down("f5");
    ms.down(UseButton);
    kb.down("e");

else
    kb.stroke("f5");
    ms.up(UseButton);
    
    end 
    
end
```

any help would be fine. would like to have a code only in three steps with an ended mouse up
...LUA is not mine...

Answer (score 1):

i think, i found a valid solution by myself:

```
    actions.command7 = function ()

if (f5) then

    if (Lift) then
        ms.up(UseButton);
        kb.up("e");
        Lift = not Lift;
    else
        kb.stroke("f5");
        f5 = not f5;
    end
else
    kb.stroke("f5");
    ms.down(UseButton);
    kb.down("e");
    f5 = true;
    Lift = true;
end
end
```